# angularjs radio acting weird

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im using this approach:

```
<tr class="radio-row" ng-repeat="topurchase in vm.firmstopurchase">

                    <td >
                        <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red">
                        {{ topurchase.name }}</td>

                </tr>
```

but in my code, i can somehow select multiple of them, and they have weird names:

while looking in the source code after the ng-repeat is done i see:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" name="38" style="">
```

all different `name` attribute for each of the ng-repeat loops.

Why is it acting like that? How can i call it with color? cause that wont work currently..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a victim of scope inheritance issues here.  There is a rule in Angular - "Always use a dot in `ng-model`.  `ng-repeat` creates a new child scope, and any `ng-model` without a dot is not accessible outside the repeat. See [Nuances of scope prototype inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) for a more in depth look.

you appear already to be using Controller As (you have a `vm` binding).  Using `vm.color` will help here.

Also, once these are all hooked up correctly to the controller, they will all select simultaneously, since you are setting all their values to the same thing.  you can use `ng-value` to hook the radio up to the object, or to a property on the object.  (eg. `ng-value="topurchase"` would set the `ng-model` to the specific object, or `ng-value="topurchase.name"` would set it equal to the `name` property.

In summary, change `ng-model` to reference your controller, and use `ng-value` instead of `value`.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
   vm.firmstopurchase = [
     {name: 'red', number: 1},
     {name: 'blue', number: 2},
     {name: 'yellow', number: 3},
     ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <table>
    <tr class="radio-row" ng-repeat="topurchase in vm.firmstopurchase">

      <td>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.color" ng-value="topurchase"> {{ topurchase.name }}</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
  {{vm.color}}
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/f2Cv5vr02sLHYsZyiYsf?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I did also read the in dept post and replies .  Accepted your answer . Do you have time for a other question too ?